# What is best way to lookup a list of integers in a list of ranged integers in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I have a list of ranges as shown below:

[image: list of ranges]

I have a list of values as shown below:

[image]

Now what I need to do is, for every value in the "List of Values", I need to get the index of the row in the "List of Ranges", such that the value falls in between "From" and "To" of that row in the "List of Ranges".

Assumptions:

- Both the list are dataframes (I would prefer to do this is pyspark)
- There can be overlaps in the "List of Ranges", in that case return all the possible range indexes
- The From and To values are Inclusive
- "List of Ranges" can have more than a 100 million rows
- Length of "List of Values" will be always less than the "List of Ranges". (Even though my picture doesn't show that)

Explaining the above with example,

First item in the "List of values" is '17', and the range to which it falls will be at index 2 of "List of Ranges" as 17 is between 15 and 19.

Second item in the "List of values" is '51', and the range to which it falls will be at index 9 of "List of Ranges" as 51 is between 50 and 54.

I would like to if there is any fast/efficient way of doing the lookup on the ranges in pyspark.

Comment: Are the indexes actually some ID columns in your DataFrames? Or you want the row number?

Comment: Actually I want the row number. More specifically i should be able to get values of other columns, if it exist, from the same row number of the belonging range..

Comment: give an output example then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Pyspark 1.6+: use a non-equi join to find the matching ranges. Then, as you will have more rows than `values` initially had, because the ranges can be overlapping, group by the values and call `collect_list`.

I’ve added an example of values that don’t fall within the ranges. If you don’t care about them, change how the dataframes are joined to `left`.

```py
ranges = spark.createDataFrame(((1, 0, 5), (2, 4, 7), (3, 8, 10)),
                               schema=("index", "from", "to"))
values = spark.createDataFrame(((-1,), (3,), (5,), (8,), (100,)),
                               schema=("value",))
df2 = ranges.join(values,
                  values.value.between(ranges["from"], ranges["to"]),
                  how="right")  # change to left outliers should be ignored
df2.groupBy("value").agg(collect_list("index").alias("range_indices")).show()
# +-----+-------------+
# |value|range_indices|
# +-----+-------------+
# |    5|       [1, 2]|
# |  100|           []|
# |    3|          [1]|
# |    8|          [3]|
# |   -1|           []|
# +-----+-------------+
```

Comment: I have ranges dataframe length = 11864603 and values dataframe length = 504719. The join was done in like 0.04 seconds,  but the moment I try to do a show, the operation get aborted with an exception "org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in Future.get: "

Comment: @Sen, yes, that's not a problem. I merely gave a small example to show how it works. The solution provided here scales to “big data” as well.

Comment: Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.OutOfMemorySparkException: Size of broadcasted table far exceeds estimates and exceeds limit of spark.driver.maxResultSize=4294967296. You can disable broadcasts for this query using set spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=-1

Comment: Did you manually call `broadcast` on any of the 2 frames? If so, don’t. Otherwise, execute `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", "-1")` and possibly `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "2001")` (or a large number), to increase the number of partitions used during this join operation.

Comment: Nope. I didnt manually call broadcast at all. I am running this in a Databricks cluster and it throws this error. I tried spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", "-1"), but the error still came up. I haven't tried this (spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "2001")), but i will and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

This should work on Spark 2.1+:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_ranges = df_ranges.withColumn("id", F.monotonically_increasing_id())
df = df_vals.crossJoin(df_ranges)
df = df.where((F.col('val') >= F.col('from')) & (F.col('value') <= F.col('to')))
df = df.groupby('val').agg(F.collect_set('id').alias('ids'))
df.show()

        +------+-----------+
        |   val|        ids|
        +------+-----------+
        |    17|        [2]|
        |    51|        [9]|
        +------+-----------+
```

Comment: Isn't this operation "df.where((F.col('val') >= F.col('from')) & (F.col('value') <= F.col('to')))" a slow one as it will require a full table scan..

Comment: you must scan the full table since the answer could potentially be of the size of the values times the ranges

Comment: I was thinking in the line of applying a udf on every row, and make spark handle it the most efficient way. Will the highlighted operation in your solution also works the same way?

Comment: udf are slow, but even so, again, in any solution, you cannot avoid crossing between all values and ranges, since the answer could include all of them.